# Efficient way of reading Config file

Tags: java, file-io, config

We're developing a Java application that reads a Config file at runtime. My question is that which of the following scenario is efficient for reading a Config file.

> Scenario #1: Retrieves a value from config by opening the file, get the value, then close the file.

So this means that file will be open and close every time retrieving a value.

> Scenario #2: Open the file during initialization, then expose the object statically across the runtime.

File will be open once, then retrieving a value using the Config object.

Honestly, we currently using the scenario #2. A reason why we choose it because Config file will be open once. Opening file needs syncrhonization, which may lead to untimely retrieval of value. Also, scenario #1 may cause runtime error if the Config file is moved from it's absolute path (anything is possible). But scenario #1 is efficient when it comes in modifying the Config values during runtime.

So which is efficient?

Comment: I would imagine that the answer to this is dependent on the requirements of the configuration objects. If you are expecting to change the parameters at runtime, then only #1 would be acceptable.

However, if you are expecting that the parameters do not change often and a restart is acceptable, I personally would (and have) go with #2

Comment: Depends on how many reads you are doing from this file, and how big the file is. If the file is using key-value pairs throughout, you can cache only those key-values which are recently requested (or most often used) rather than keep the entire file available statically. If you have a huge disparity in data you would need to cache, and the file is prohibitively large, you need to start thinking about a DB

Comment: It also depends on how often do you think you will change the config file... I assume not really often, so I would implement S #2 with some button to trigger a reload of the config file but it depends on your application an the surrounding scenario.

Comment: Can you give us an idea of how often you intend to read, how static your values are etc? Typically the technique is to read once, store the required values (rather than the entire object) and then re-check at a reasonable interval or when you're about to perform something critical which relies on a config value. But it depends how often you use the values, and in what way

Answer (score 0):

Is your application a mulit-threaded application? if yes, you need to make sure that you have scenario #1 with necessary synchronisation and semaphores. The reason is that your config file is a general item in your application which will be used by all the threads. You don't want the config file reading operation to be interleaved. Even with single threaded operation, it is good to do #1 because you will have less chances of having IO Error. The RTE that you mentioned in your question can happen with anything if you decide to move the file (? Why would you if you need it at a certain place?).

Answer (score 0):

If I should have to access the file more than once, probably I would create a `class` with a field for each configuration, I would read the file once (only to initialize the class fields) and then I would close the file. In this way you read the file once, during the init, and then you could simply access the configuration by reading the field values stored in the class.

```
public class Configuration
{
    private static String confOne;

    private static int confTwo;

    private static boolean confThree;


    public static init(File configFile) {
        /* read the file and init fields */
    }


    public static String getConfigOne() {
        return configOne;
    }

    public static int getConfigTwo() {
        return configOne;
    }

    public static boolean getConfigThree() {
        return configOne;
    }
}
```

A little advice: tries to never hold open a file (or resources) unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think neither of the scenarios is the best one:

As you you have already stated in sencario #1 you may have a lot of unnecessary IO-Workload and in #2 you cannot change config parameters dynamically at runtime.

I suggest to use a mixture of both. You can load your configuration statically once and then check periodically, if changes have happend. If so, reload your config.

You can see how it may be done by inspecting Java's ResourceBundle-Class. In fact, if the config can be placed as properties-file in your classpath, you can (ab?)use this implementation for your purpose:

```java
    private static Control MY_CONTROL = new Control()
    {        
        @Override
        public long getTimeToLive(String baseName, Locale locale)
        {
            return MY_TTL; //make shure, that changes are checked periodically
        }
    };

    public static String getParamter(String name)
    {
        ResourceBundle config = ResourceBundle.getBundle("config", MY_CONTROL);
        return config.getString(name);
    }
```